# How restrict the year in jquery datepicker?such that it display no year other than current year in database

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

How to set jquery.datepick.js to display only the current year in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai change the year range from yearRange: '-99:+100', To yearRange: '-1:+100',so that we can get the dates from the year before current year say the dropdown will display the year starting from 2009 since the current year is 2010

Comment: This does not really work. If this year is 2012 and my year range is '-1:+100' I get 2011 - 2112, which is fine. However, If I select 2112 and then I want to change it back to 2012 I cant. The new date range goes from 2111 - 2212.

Answer (score 3):

If it is the datepicker from JQuery UI  you can give it min and max date as arguments like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2010, 1 , 1), 
    maxDate: new Date(2010,12,31)
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: no that doesnt work for me Can i send the jquerycode for ur reference

Comment: Sure you can. I will have a look at it

Comment: I got the result 
I did tis to get the result
Hai change the year range from yearRange: '-99:+100', To yearRange: '-1:+100',so that we can get the dates from the year before current year say the dropdown will display the year starting from 2009 since the current year is 2010